# Include logged value in an integer vector

Tags: r

Is it possible to include log of something to an integer vector in R? I am trying to understand how log/abs coerce automatically within an integer vector. 
x <- c(1L,2L,4L,log(100)L)
The above doesn't work. What is the correct method for including log?

Comment: What do you mean "include". What is your expected output? Do you want to round log(100) to the nearest integer?

Comment: Or use `as.integer()`? Like `as.integer(c(1, 2, 4, log(100))`? Alternately `c(1L, 2L, 4L, as.integer(log(100)))`...

Comment: Thanks all for the response. I read in a book that mathematical functions like log will be automatically coerced to double or integer. For example x <- c(1,2,3,log(100)) automatically coerces the type of log(100) in this vector to double. But i wanted to know when and how such functions will be coerced automatically to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**as.numeric()** would be the appropriate method for storing a log value.

If you store **as.integer()**, you will be unable to store the precise value, and will be forced to round to the nearest whole number in order to coerce the value to integer format.

If you want to see what happens when pushing a log into integer format:

```
as.integer(log(100))

    #[1] 4
```

vs

```
as.numeric(log(100))

    #[1] 4.60517
```

The same concept applies to a **vector of log values**:

```
as.integer(c(log(100),log(200),log(999)))

#[1] 4 5 6
```

vs

```
as.numeric(c(log(100),log(200),log(999)))

#[1] 4.605170 5.298317 6.906755
```

vs

```
round(as.numeric(c(log(100),log(200),log(999))),2)

#[1] 4.61 5.30 6.91
```

Comment: OP might want to consider `round()` as an alternative to `as.integer()` (the latter always truncates)